# Iterating over 3D numpy array, creating a copy and set new values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

Hello python community,

I am new to python and playing around with numpy arrays and have a question.
E.g. I have this 3D array (in reality the array is much much bigger)

```
input = np.array([[[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2]],[[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2]]])
```

and I want to replace the 2s with 0s to get:

```
result = np.array([[[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0]],[[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0]]])
```

Is there an efficient/fast way to do this?
The only thing I know is to iterate with `for x in range ...` but that's probably not very efficient is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
inp = np.array(
    [
        [[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]],
        [[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]],
    ]
)

inp = np.where(inp == 2, 0, inp)
print(inp)
```

Prints:

```
[[[0 0 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 0 0]]

 [[0 0 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1 0 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter to indices that are `2` and replace:

```
arr = np.array([[[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2]],[[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2]]])
arr[arr == 2] = 0
```

output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]])
```